# cmd: save wmic output to variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wmic

I am trying to get the timestamp of a file into a variable in a batch file.

My batch file, imagetime.bat contains the following:

```
set targetfile=%~1
set targetfile=%targetfile:\=\\%
echo %targetfile%
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ( `wmic datafile where name^="%targetfile%" get creationdate` ) do ( echo %%i )
echo %timestamp%
```

And I get this output:

```
C:\>imagetime.bat V:\setup.exe

C:\>set targetfile=V:\setup.exe

C:\>set targetfile=V:\\setup.exe

C:\>echo V:\\setup.exe
V:\\setup.exe

C:\>for /F "usebackq delims=" %i in (`wmic datafile where name="V:\\setup.exe" g
et creationdate`) do (echo %i  )

  ) (echo CreationDate
 reationDate

  ) (echo 20110412103858.000000+***
 0110412103858.000000+***

  ) (echo
ECHO is on.

C:\>echo ""
""

C:\>
```

Of course, at the end I would like to see "20110412103858.000000+***", so that I can format it as "04/12/2011,10:38:58" with cmd's string manipulation.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I tried Hackoo's solution. It works for calc.exe but not for V:\setup.exe. Having removed @echo off and pause I get this output (I changed the line referring to calc.exe to: `set "targetfile=V:\setup.exe"`):

```
C:\>hackoo_calc.bat

C:\>set "targetfile=C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe"

C:\>set targetfile=C:\\Windows\\system32\\calc.exe

C:\>for /F "usebackq delims=" %i in (`wmic datafile where name="C:\\Windows\\sys
tem32\\calc.exe" get creationdate`) do (for %b in (%i) do (set "timestamp=%b" )
)

) do (set "timestamp=%b" ) )

C:\>(set "timestamp=CreationDate" )

) do (set "timestamp=%b" ) ) 1.688252+120

C:\>(set "timestamp=20090714015711.688252+120" )

) do (set "timestamp=%b" ) )

C:\>echo TimeStamp : "20090714015711.688252+120"
TimeStamp : "20090714015711.688252+120"

C:\>hackoo_setup.bat

C:\>set "targetfile=V:\setup.exe"

C:\>set targetfile=V:\\setup.exe

C:\>for /F "usebackq delims=" %i in (`wmic datafile where name="V:\\setup.exe" g
et creationdate`) do (for %b in (%i) do (set "timestamp=%b" ) )

) do (set "timestamp=%b" ) )

C:\>(set "timestamp=CreationDate" )

) do (set "timestamp=%b" ) ) 8.000000+***

) do (set "timestamp=%b" ) )

C:\>echo TimeStamp : "CreationDate"
TimeStamp : "CreationDate"

C:\>
```

Comment: You are not assigning the output from the WMIC command to a variable. All you are doing is echoing it to the screen.

Comment: @Squashman: yes, I should have written set instead of echo.

Comment: z32a7ul, after trying Hackoo's solution, did you try mine? It should do exactly what your question asked as well as perform the manipulation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this do what you want?

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "TF=%~f1"
Set "TS="
For /F "Skip=1" %%A In ('WMIC DataFile Where^
 "Name='%TF:\=\\%'" Get CreationDate') Do For %%B In (%%~nA) Do Set "TS=%%B"
If Not Defined TS Exit /B
Set "TS=%TS:~4,2%/%TS:~6,2%/%TS:~,4%,%TS:~-6,2%:%TS:~-4,2%:%TS:~-2%"
Echo %TS%
Pause
```

**[Edit]**

Here it is again without the caret using your normal commandline style:

With `UseBackQ`:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "TF=%~f1"
Set "TS="
For /F "UseBackQ Skip=1" %%A In (`
    "WMIC DataFile Where Name="%TF:\=\\%" Get CreationDate"
`) Do For %%B In (%%~nA) Do Set "TS=%%B"
If Not Defined TS Exit /B
Set "TS=%TS:~4,2%/%TS:~6,2%/%TS:~,4%,%TS:~-6,2%:%TS:~-4,2%:%TS:~-2%"
Echo %TS%
Pause
```

Without `UseBackQ`: *(preferred)*

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "TF=%~f1"
Set "TS="
For /F "Skip=1" %%A In ('
    "WMIC DataFile Where Name="%TF:\=\\%" Get CreationDate"
') Do For %%B In (%%~nA) Do Set "TS=%%B"
If Not Defined TS Exit /B
Set "TS=%TS:~4,2%/%TS:~6,2%/%TS:~,4%,%TS:~-6,2%:%TS:~-4,2%:%TS:~-2%"
Echo %TS%
Pause
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I'm not sure of some points. Can you confirm/clarify these: (1) line 4-5: ^[Enter][Space] is not required, it's just for making lines shorter.

Comment: (2) Why is it that in a batch file I have to write "Name=x", while on the command line I have to write Name="x"?

Comment: (3) %%~nA gets the filename part of %%a, which can be used to remove microseconds. So, does this also work if the user locale specifies comma (,) instead of dot (.) as the decimal separator? Or does wmic use always the dot (.) as decimal separator?

Comment: (4) Usually I see scripts with usebackq, is it not applicable here? I tried putting it before Skip and replacing all single quotes with backquotes but it did not work.

Comment: `WMIC`'s `CreationDate` output is the same regardless of locale changes and yes, I used the caret **`^`** to shorten the line because it would have been longer than `80` characters.

Comment: @z32a7ul, I have added some examples as an Edit to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of batch file that can store the variable Timestamp from WMIC using this method :

```bat
@echo off
set "targetfile=%windir%\system32\calc.exe"
set targetfile=%targetfile:\=\\%
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ( `wmic datafile where name^="%targetfile%" get creationdate` ) do (
    for %%b in (%%i) do (
        set "timestamp=%%b"
    )   
)
echo TimeStamp : "%timestamp%"
pause
```

**Edit :** Adding function to Convert WMIDate to Date :

```bat
@echo off
set "targetfile=%windir%\system32\calc.exe"
set targetfile=%targetfile:\=\\%
for /f "skip=1 usebackq delims=" %%i in ( `wmic datafile where name^="%targetfile%" get creationdate` ) do (
    for %%b in (%%i) do (
        set "TS=%%b"
    )   
)
echo TimeStamp : "%TS%"
Call :ConvertTS2Date "%TS%" ConvertedDate
echo Converted TimeStamp : "%ConvertedDate%"
pause & exit
::***********************************************************************
:ConvertTS2Date <WMIDate> <Date2Set>
(
echo Wscript.echo WMIDateStringToDate("%~1"^)
echo Function WMIDateStringToDate(dtmDate^) 
echo     WMIDateStringToDate = CDate(Mid(dtmDate, 5, 2^) ^& "/" ^& _ 
echo         Mid(dtmDate, 7, 2^) ^& "/" ^& Left(dtmDate, 4^) _ 
echo             ^& " " ^& Mid (dtmDate, 9, 2^) ^& ":" ^& _ 
echo                 Mid(dtmDate, 11, 2^) ^& ":" ^& Mid(dtmDate, _ 
echo                     13, 2^)^) 
echo End Function
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"') do (set %2=%%a)
Del "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Exit /b
::***********************************************************************
```

The output result is like this for my case :

> ```
> TimeStamp : "20170929125013.781773+060"
> Converted TimeStamp : "29-09-2017 12:50:13"
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer with the output of your code.

Comment: I upvoted yours too, but I accepted Compo's answer because that one works also if the timestamp ends in xxx, e.g. 20110412103858.000000+xxx. x stands for star but SO would interpret it as bold.

Answer (score 0):

`wmic` outputs more than one line, so your variable gets overwritten several times (last one with an empy string). But there is just one line with a `=`, so just one line with a second token after `=`. Using `"tokens=2 delims=="` gives you just the desired value:

```
@echo off
set "targetfile=%~f0"
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic datafile where name^="%targetfile:\=\\%" get CreationDate /value') do set "timestamp=%%I"
echo [%timestamp%]
```