# cmd: Pass oldest creationdate from "WMIC process where name='<name.exe>' get creationdate" into a variable where one process has >1 date outputs

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd, wmic

Ultimate goal is to delete temp files belonging the the earliest created named process.

Current results of command:

```
>wmic process where name='<xyz.exe>' get creationdate


CreationDate

20230209140434.535724+000

20230209140527.350080+000
```

How do I single out the oldest of the above, and pass it into a variable?

I've attempted examples given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674006/cmd-save-wmic-output-to-variable)

**Update**

My code:

```bash
@echo off

for /f %%i in ('wmic process where name^="<xyz.exe>" get creationdate') do (
    for %%b in (%%i) do (
        set "TS=%%i"
    )
)
echo TimeStamp : "%TS%"
```

The above results in passing the newest creationdate.

**Update2**

Attempted the following first:

```bash
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('wmic process where name^="xyz.exe" get creationdate ^| sort) do (
    for %%b in (%%i) do (
        set "TS=%%i"
    )
)
echo TimeStamp : "%TS%"
```

The above returns:

```
TimeStamp : CreationDate
```

If I change the code to:

```bash
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('wmic process where name^="xyz.exe" get creationdate ^| sort /r) do (
    for %%b in (%%i) do (
        set "TS=%%i"
    )
)
echo TimeStamp : "%TS%"
```

This returns the date I'm looking for.

However, why does the first set of code, in **Update2**, return the header?

Comment: The expectation is that we assist you with the code you've attempted. As you haven't submitted it, you seem to be expecting somebody else to write it for you. This site does not offer a free code writing service, nor does it walk you through task, step by step. Please use the [Edit] link, to add the missing code to your question, along with the debugging information. BTW, my fist instinct, if the results aren't already in order, would be to pipe the results through the `sort.exe` utility, as the format of the times should be sortable.

Comment: updated to reflect my current code

Comment: You are asking the code to perform your `do` portion against each line of output returned by the parenthesized command. The header is part of that output. BTW, I'm certain you should be using ```set "TS=%%b"```, not ```set "TS=%%i"```.